# How to count rows that got copied from one Hive table to another

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am moving data from one hive table to another hive table. While moving data, I add few new columns add partition and also applying compression.

I wanted to know if there is an easy way to know that number of rows moved from one table to another are same. Just to validate the moving data action.
Currently I am doing count on both table, which is taking too much time as number of rows are in 10^10 magnitude.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a map-reduce job is triggered during the transfer of data from first table to the second, you can use the RECORDS counter from map/reduce to validate the row count.

Comment: Well I am not writing any Map-Reduce job, I am just writing Hive query in my java code and executing the query. Query looks something like below, which I generate dynamically based on different tables.
INSERT TABLE SecondTable
Select col1, col2 ... 
FROM FirstTable

Comment: Run this command from hive shell: hive>set hive.execution.engine; If this shows value as mr, then a map reduce job is triggered during the transferred by hive to move the data from source table. You should see the job id in the logs.

Comment: it shows mr, I know that map reduce job is triggered. How do put a counter or how do I access reducer task at run time in my code.
My code is simply executing the Hive script and mapper-reducer generation happen under the hood.

Comment: Counters are added by map reduce framework to the job. A job id and url to track is given when job is triggered and you can use to access the counters from that page. Alternatively you can use api as given here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html#Job_Counters_API

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was looking in the admin and saw all counters.
There are few tables which has countergroupname = HIVE which has RECORDS_IN and RECORDS_OUT info having correct counts, but few tables does not have such group ? Also how to get JOB ID at run time ?

Comment: RECORDS_IN and RECORDS_OUT should be sufficient for your use case. Other counters are filled by map task and reduce task independently and can be used to debug jobs. JOBID will be available in the logs[stdout] once your trigger the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there is a way to find out JOBID programatically ?